# json_encode as per keys

Tags: php, arrays, json

For example I have php array as:

```
$arr = ["a"=>[],"b"=>[]];
```

for which I need json object as:

```
{"a":[],"b":{}}
```

I have huge array for which json_encode function is applied. If I put option as `json_encode($data,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` then it will make every `[]` object to `{}` object which is highly undesirable.

Can I apply encode option specific to array keys? Because one should be able to make `{"a":[],"b":{}}` from php array which is valid json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) for this, like([DEMO](https://3v4l.org/VHTYq)):

```
$arr = ["a"=>[],"b"=>new class{}];
```

This way you can collectively turn some keys into objects and others into arrays.

You can also use the typecast [`(object)`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting), like([DEMO](https://3v4l.org/JGEfo)):

```
$arr = ["a"=>[],"b"=>(object)[]];
```

I would personally prefer the typecasting method.